# BigQuery Write API Java - PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'TABLES_UPDATE_DATA' denied on resource

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created a service account and gave it a number of permissions, including owner and BigQuery data editor/owner.

The email has owner permissions and also all the relevant bigquery permissions.

I downloaded the key JSON file, I can see it is there and referenced correctly after adding it to my environment variables, but when the `createWriteStream()` method is called, I receive:

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'TABLES_UPDATE_DATA' denied on resource
'projects/<PROJECT-ID>/datasets/D1/tables/T1' (or it may not exist).
```

I made sure that the project ID is the correct one, and the table name and dataset name are also correct.

The failure occurs on the last line of the below block:

```
WriteStream stream = WriteStream.newBuilder().setType(WriteStream.Type.COMMITTED).build();
TableName parentTable = TableName.of(projectId, DATASET_NAME, TABLE_NAME);
CreateWriteStreamRequest createWriteStreamRequest =
                    CreateWriteStreamRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setParent(parentTable.toString())
                            .setWriteStream(stream)
                            .build();
WriteStream writeStream = client.createWriteStream(createWriteStreamRequest);
```

Let me also clarify I am under the free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Solved -- Free tier seemingly doesnt allow you to do this